# How do I debug this javascript centering issue?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, element, centering

Hoping someone with more experienced eyes than myself can help me identify where I've gone wrong here.

I'm struggling to get the four child elements of the parent div 'winImg' to center horizontally in javascript (children are all images called 'leader', 'follower1', 'follower2' and 'follower3').

```
``function winGame() {
 update(locations[6]);

 const winImg = document.getElementById('win-img');

 leader.src = "https://preview.redd.it/what-is-rataus-history-with-his-cult-and-ratoo-v0-au38e19g4zjc1.gif?width=360&auto=webp&s=c8bbc859a9ce2851b0d5f699c0eb9a8f4f011b00";

 follower1.src = "https://preview.redd.it/patch-notes-1-1-5-v0-f8awrb2dfcsa1.gif?width=194&auto=webp&s=34ea76918584d5b33804319d1ec59a0bf9b48914";

 follower2.src = "https://preview.redd.it/patch-notes-1-1-5-v0-f8awrb2dfcsa1.gif?width=194&auto=webp&s=34ea76918584d5b33804319d1ec59a0bf9b48914";

 follower3.src = "https://preview.redd.it/patch-notes-1-1-5-v0-f8awrb2dfcsa1.gif?    width=194&auto=webp&s=34ea76918584d5b33804319d1ec59a0bf9b48914";

 winImg.style.display = "flex";
 winImg.style.flexDirection = "row";
 winImg.style.justifyContent = "center";
 winImg.style.padding = "1rem";
 winImg.style.maxWidth = "550px";

 leader.style.display = "block";
 leader.style.margin = "0 auto"; 
 leader.style.width = "6rem"; 
 leader.style.height = "6rem"; 

 follower1.style.display = "block";
 follower1.style.margin = "0 auto"; 
 follower1.style.width = "3rem"; 
 follower1.style.height = "5rem";

 follower2.style.display = "block";
 follower2.style.margin = "0 auto";
 follower2.style.width = "3rem"; 
 follower2.style.height = "5rem"; 

 follower3.style.display = "block";
 follower3.style.margin = "0 auto"; 
 follower3.style.width = "3rem"; 
 follower3.style.height = "5rem"; 

 }`
```

`
As you can see, I tried block display and margin '0 auto' for the children images then flex display with rows for the parent div so the images will all be on the same line. I expected them to be centred but they are left aligned.

Comment: without the HTML, or knowing what most of those variable even are, telling you what you're doing wrong is difficult. Do you, for example, get any errors in the browser *developer* tools console?

Comment: they're nicely aligned inside the 550px "winImg" ... the position of "winImg" is probably left since you haven't done a thing about it

Comment: mmm i did style winImg so that it was flex display with justify content as center. is that not enough to center the element?

Comment: No errors in console or identified problems in vs code. Thanks for trying anyway, I guess I'll keep playing around with it. Probably good practise.